# Meteor Can't find core files

Tags: javascript, meteor

I was working on an application user Meteor.js, and I changed the name of an input in my html file. When the server refreshed, the log in safari output error messages saying that it couldn't find variable Template or Meteor, as well as other core parts of Meteor.

I have already tried several things, such as reinstalling meteor, reverting back to an old commit, and even creating a fresh starter project just to see if my project was broken or not. Nothing worked, and I continue to get the same error messages. I tried on several browsers, but the problem originated with I was using safari on my localhost. Unfortunately I cannot post an image of the error log, but include in it are

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating Package.session.Session)`

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Template`

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Meteor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: there was something strange going on with Safari. After restarting my computer and opening a fresh safari window, all is working as expected